# WCF recieves a complex object as null

Tags: c#, wcf, object

After getting input in another thread here on the forum [StackOverFlow][1]

[1]: [Getting a nullreference when passing a complex object from KSOAP2 to WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690566/getting-a-nullreference-when-passing-a-complex-object-from-ksoap2-to-wcf) have i reached conclusion that my problem is with the WCF service itself. It seems that the service is not able to understand the object that it's receiving.

No matter what I do the object passed is always null.

I have even tried declaring the datamember explicit even though it should not be necessary in the current version of WCF.

Here's the class I'm trying to pass through the WCF:

```
namespace ModelLayer
{

        [DataContract]
        public class User   
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Mac { get; set; }

            public User()
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

My service interface:

```
[ServiceContract (Namespace = "http://nordahl.org/")]
    public interface IWcfFoodAndAllergi
    {

        [OperationContract]
        int InsertUser(User _user);

        [OperationContract]
        User GetUser(string _mac);

        [OperationContract]
        int InsertRecipe(Recipe _recipe);

        [OperationContract]
        List<Recipe> GetRecipeByAllergi(List<Allergies> _allergies);

        [OperationContract]
        List<Recipe> GetRecipeByType(string _type);

        [OperationContract]
        List<Recipe> GetRecipeByName(string _name);


    }

}
```

And lastly the webconfig file itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <remove fileExtension=".cs"/>
          <add fileExtension=".cs" allowed="true"/>

        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>

          <services>
      <service name="WcfFoodAndAllergi.WcfFoodAndAllergi">
        <!-- Use a bindingNamespace to eliminate tempuri.org -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding ="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingNamespace="http://nordahl.org/"
                  contract="WcfFoodAndAllergi.IWcfFoodAndAllergi"
        />
      </service>
    </services>


    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours when a complex object referenced another complex object in a T4 generated class.  If you are using an include in an obtain method, or another method relating to Entity or objects linking complex objects to each other; you may get a circular reference error.  I had a friend show me how to fix this with a custom class that sets up an attribute:

[Complex Object won't return when using 'include' syntax in WCF with Entity Version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922962/complex-object-wont-return-when-using-include-syntax-in-wcf-with-entity-versi?noredirect=1#comment38757094_24922962)