# Complex Object won't return when using 'include' syntax in WCF with Entity Version 6

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5, entity-framework-6, t4

Okay so this one has got me stumped as I just see that my client basically disconnects and terminates when returning an object with 'include'.  However it works fine without that across a WCF SERVICE.  The problem is that I really want those connected objects set up through navigation.

Basically the code is a complex object return:

```
public teCIF getCif(int aCifId)
        {
            using (CIFContainer context = GetCifContext())
            {
                var thing = context.teCIFs
                    .Include("Product_TYPE")
                    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.CIF_ID == aCifId);

                return thing;
            }
        }
```

Now the weird thing is that this will work JUST FINE when I comment out the include statement.  It is like the complex type being sent over the WCF service does not like the include statement and just says: "nope, not going to do that".

For reference my Complex Object I have already hacked at quite a bit as it is a T4 generated object from a database (abbreviated):

```
[Serializable]
    public partial class teCIF
    {
        public int CIF_ID { get; set; }
        public string CUSTOMER_NAME { get; set; }
        public string SITE_NAME { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
        public int PRODUCT_TYPE_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual tlPRODUCT_TYPE Product_TYPE { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update for linking copmplex item:**

```
[Serializable]
public partial class tlPRODUCT_TYPE
{
    public tlPRODUCT_TYPE()
    {
        this.teCIFs = new HashSet<teCIF>();
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public int PRODUCT_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<teCIF> teCIFs { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried removing attributes but have not yet messed with the 'data member' type that WCF likes.  I just don't get why this does not work as I have sworn I have done this in the past Entity Version 4 with complex types with navigation properties related to other complex types.

Comment: are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: Yes, it was basically having the WCF forcifully terminate but not tell me why exactly.  Issue was with cyclic reference, I got it.

Comment: What is the code for `tlPRODUCT_TYPE`?

Comment: @Erik I updated my question.  It would be interesting to deal with this without adding a custom attribute that my friend told me.  However I had issues constantly with serializing complex types with Entity Version 6 to XML.  So I basically ignored Interfaces and other items that would blow up in my t4.

Comment: Alright so there is your problem.  It is trying to serialize `teCIF` and that class points to `tblPRODUCT_TYPE` which also points back to a collection of `teCIF`.  You most likely have a circular reference (99.99% chance).  What do you actually want to serialize, and what don't you want to serialize?

Comment: Yep, see my response below.  A friend of mine had a similar issue and told me how to fix it with a class to implement an attribute that handles the circular reference error.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so I actually got help from a friend but figured that this could come up for others so I should answer the question as it may help someone else.  I had to add a custom attribute that I make a class for that determines cyclic references.  Basically the pointers to the navigation were somehow getting lost when using WCF, but were fine when not hooked up to a service.  This is not good as I want my service to be hosting the methods using WCF, not just client calls directly using Entity V6.

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICifService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [CyclicReferencesAware(true)]
        teCIF getCif(int aCifId);
    }
```

The implementation class works like this:

```
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Description;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class CyclicReferencesAwareAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IOperationBehavior
    {
        private readonly bool _on = true;

        public CyclicReferencesAwareAttribute(bool on)
        {
            _on = on;
        }

        public bool On
        {
            get { return _on; }
        }

        #region IOperationBehavior Members

        void IOperationBehavior.AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        void IOperationBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {
            CyclicReferencesAwareContractBehavior.ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operationDescription, On);
        }

        void IOperationBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            CyclicReferencesAwareContractBehavior.ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operationDescription, On);
        }

        void IOperationBehavior.Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
        }

        #endregion

        #region IContractBehavior Members

        void IContractBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        void IContractBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            CyclicReferencesAwareContractBehavior.ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehaviors(contractDescription, On);
        }

        void IContractBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            CyclicReferencesAwareContractBehavior.ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehaviors(contractDescription, On);
        }

        void IContractBehavior.Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class CyclicReferencesAwareContractBehavior : IContractBehavior
    {
        private const int MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;
        private const bool IgnoreExtensionDataObject = false;

        private bool _on;

        public CyclicReferencesAwareContractBehavior(bool on)
        {
            _on = on;
        }

        #region IContractBehavior Members

        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehaviors(contractDescription, _on);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehaviors(contractDescription, _on);
        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        internal static void ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehaviors(ContractDescription contractDescription, bool on)
        {
            foreach (var operation in contractDescription.Operations)
            {
                ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operation, on);
            }
        }

        internal static void ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(OperationDescription operation, bool on)
        {
            if (operation.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior)) || operation.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ApplyCyclicDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior)))
            {
                operation.Behaviors.Add(new ApplyCyclicDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operation, MaxItemsInObjectGraph, IgnoreExtensionDataObject, on));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }

    internal class ApplyCyclicDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
    {
        private readonly int _maxItemsInObjectGraph;
        private readonly bool _ignoreExtensionDataObject;
        private readonly bool _preserveObjectReferences;

        public ApplyCyclicDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, int maxItemsInObjectGraph, bool ignoreExtensionDataObject, bool preserveObjectReferences)
            : base(operationDescription)
        {
            _maxItemsInObjectGraph = maxItemsInObjectGraph;
            _ignoreExtensionDataObject = ignoreExtensionDataObject;
            _preserveObjectReferences = preserveObjectReferences;
        }

        public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
        {
            return new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes, _maxItemsInObjectGraph, _ignoreExtensionDataObject, _preserveObjectReferences, null /*dataContractSurrogate*/);
        }

        public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
        {
            return new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes, _maxItemsInObjectGraph, _ignoreExtensionDataObject, _preserveObjectReferences, null /*dataContractSurrogate*/);
        }
    }
```

Once I applied this attribute to any Operation in my interface for my service, it worked fine for any complex type.

Comment: It basically presents an option to know of cyclic references.  I did not dive deep into this one to investigate all behaviors.  Basically the Interfaces override default settings with an input boolean in the attribute and then has internal methods in the class to override the serialization.

Comment: Where did it come from? Is it part of EF? WCF?

Comment: I am guessing WCF.  You set it on either the Method invocation as an attribute or else as an attribute to the whole interface you use for your WCF contract for an endpoint.  I know it saved me a whole lot of headache of having to manually either hack a T4 for some time or creating my own complex objects that I pieced from context objects.

Comment: It's possible that it came from "[Cyclic Reference Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67f4b9d5-7cc9-4223-9754-20c116d9ff28/cyclic-reference-question)".